# Bindparam and Like condition when querying

Tags: sql, parameters, conditional-statements, sql-like

I have this function that should just look in the database for a name similars to an user input. However I can't use Like with the param :uname. 
Everyone I look in the web they suggest me to do something like this

```
$username = "$%username%";
```

However the query doesn't return any result.

I know the database is properly made because if I ask this, it returns the proper answer

```
SELECT *  FROM $schema.pessoa WHERE nome LIKE %Mike%
```

However in my code $username contains "Mike" and yet it doesn't return anything, I assumed %username hadn't be properly made however if I make an echo of it, it indeed contains the string I want- "Mike".
So the problem seems to be in the way I am questioning it with the parameter but I have no idea

```
function SearchUser($username) {
  global $dbh, $schema;
  try {
    $username = "$%username%";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *  FROM $schema.pessoa WHERE nome LIKE :uname");      
    $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if(empty($result))
       {echo 'empty';}
     return $result;
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
  $_SESSION["s_errors"]["generic"][] = "ERRO[32]: ".$e->getMessage();
  header("Location: list.php");
  die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does look right to me,

I could only suggest you try it this way and see if that makes any difference

```
$username = 'Mike';    
$stmt->bindValue(":uname", "%".$username."%");
```

Edit.

Looking at it again, this doesn't look right to me..

```
$username = '$%username%';
```

Shouldn't it be

```
$username = '%'.$username.'%';
```

Comment: Nope sorry it still doesn't work. I have no idea what's wrong.